# creating a boolean method with an array

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a static boolean method which is passed an array of objects and returns true if the array contains at least one empty object.

This is my code but it isn't accepting it, saying there are compilation errors.

```
public static boolean anyEmptyObject(object[] objects){
for(int k = 0;k<object.length; k++){
        if (objects[k].getEmpty()==true){
          return true;}
      else {return false;}
}
}
```

(getEmpty is already a declared method which returns if an object is empty or not)

not sure where my error is as it seems ok? could be my brackets?

The error is just

```
The system has detected compilation errors. This could be caused by:
Missing semicolon ; at the end of a statement.
Unclosed braces {}.
Unclosed parentheses ().
Unterminated string literals "".
Invalid method signature.
Missing return statement.
Redeclared variable or data member.
etc.
```

Comment: What's the compiler error message? Chances are, if you actually read it, it will tell you precisely what the problem is.

Comment: What error are you getting from the compiler?

Comment: *"etc."* Is that copy/pasted or edited?  The compiler typically reports line numbers.

Comment: Is `object` a custom type, or the Java type `Object`?  If it's the latter, then you'd have *runtime* issues, too.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am not using a regular compiler as this is a question for an assignment, this is all information it is reporting to me unfortunately..

Comment: The code snippet as is wouldn't cause any problems about strings/ braces/ semicolons - it's likely an error elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you put `object.length` instead of `objects.length` in your `for` loop and it should be a capital O in `Object[] objects`

Also, if you return, it will pretty much end the loop. This is not what you want.

REMEMBER: If you put a `;` that means it is the end of the line. Your indentation is going to miss the bracket after the last two `;`

```
 public static boolean anyEmptyObject(Object[] objects){
        for(int k = 0;k<objects.length; k++){
            if (objects[k].equals(null)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This will loop through your array and if it hits a null even once it will return true, if it gets through the entire array without hitting a null object then it will run through the entire for loop and then proceed to the return false statement saying there is no null objects within this array.

Comment: This is getting me somewhere, have to revise my code a bit more and will work. Thanks !

Comment: You have ; and then brackets }. The ; will end the line and it will miss the brackets.

Comment: Figured it out, replaced your if statement back to mine and it worked!

Comment: Cool, a green check would be great :D

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of object in the array?
You need to cast object first before you can invoke the member method like below

```
if (((YouClass)objects[k]).getEmpty()==true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors (and I recommend that you read carefully the compilation errors - they are often helpful)

1. the loop condition should be on `objects`, not `object`
2. the method is not guaranteed to reach a return statement (the compiler doesn't know whether you always enter the loop). Furthermore, the logic is incorrect. If you move the `return false` part out of the loop, it will be both logically and semantically correct.

Also, if you loop on objects of type java.lang.Object, don't expect them to have a getEmpty() method.